# Adobe Illustrator Stick Font To Outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I am attempting to use some single line stick fonts in some tags for engraving purposes. Everything looks good in Illustrator but I need to convert that text to a path for purposes of engraving. When I convert the stick font to outlines I lose parts of the text. For example a "-" disappears as does the horizontal component of the "A". Any suggestions on a workaround?

The font I am using is [available here](http://www.cambam.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=1557.0).

[image: sample output]
[image: before and after]

Comment: Will you show us a before/after screen shot, preferably with your font selected, so we can see the paths?

Comment: I've attached a before and after shot illustrating the two. I haven't gone through all the characters but it seems the A and the - might be the only two problems.

Comment: if you select the shapes after, are the disappearing lines there? or if you zoom in?  It might be just a rendering issue.

Comment: Good thought... but unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with those fonts, at least that's what it looks like to me.  You can see how poorly made the font is and that some of its characters are incomplete.

[image: font]

Comment: Thanks for your help! The font looks fine on my end considering that it is intended to be a "stick font" for engraving purposes. Can you elaborate?  Or perhaps you might know of an alternative font that I might use to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I have to [apply a stroke in AI](http://i.imgur.com/pViFoYh.png), just to see the font.  I'll admit, I don't do much with stick fonts so I don't know what the norm is, but I would assume that if the path were there then it would appear when given a stroke.  Maybe just draw in the missing paths by hand? @Jason

Comment: I'll see if applying a stroke can resolve the issue. If I apply a stroke, then convert the stroke outline to a path, is there a way to then grab the centerline of that? In regards to hand drawing, that would normally be good but I have a VBA script which is generating thousands of tags. It would just defeat the purpose of the automation.